# how much trigger voltages for STM32F103 rising falling edge triggered interrupts are?

Tags: stm32, interrupt

I'm a little confused about the trigger voltage for rising-falling triggered interrupts. As my previous understanding, the trigger voltage should be Vih and Vil. But some one told me Vih and Vil is not for edge triggered interrupts. The thing is, when I observe the waveform with a Oscilloscope along with an interrupt counter from Keil, I did see the interrupt happened when the voltage did not reach the Vih(rising edge). I use 3.3V voltage. The signal is only 1V around and the interrupts was triggered. I checked the manual of STM32 and did not find the answer.

Could some one help?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand how you reach your conclusion. How can you know exactly when the interrupt was triggered ?

Comment: Hi, st-link is connected to our test board with J-TAG. So I can see the counter change when interrupt happened, along with waveform in oscilloscope.

Comment: OK but how do you know exactly what voltage level triggered the interrupt ?

Comment: Hi, I do not need to know which voltage level triggered interrupt. What I can see is the peak voltage is around 1 volt.  So I feel really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The levels are the same whether you are using an interrupt or polling.

VIH min is the minimum voltage that is guaranteed to be interpreted as a high, and VIL max is the maximum input that is guaranteed to be interpreted as a low.

Any voltage between these two levels could be interpreted either way.

As well as that, there isn't a single changeover voltage because the inputs have schmitt triggers with at least 200mV of hysteresis.

To guarantee to not trigger the rising edge you need to stay below VIL max, which at 3.3V is 1.155V.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: sure. But sorry, I do not know how.Could you please let me know？

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know the reason why 'Any voltage between these two levels could be interpreted either way.'? thanks.

Comment: This is implicit in the definition of the levels.  "low max" means the maximum guaranteed to be low, which implies if you are above it you are not guaranteed to be low.  "high min" means the minimum guaranteed to be high.  if you are below it you are not guaranteed to be high.  If you are not guaranteed to be low and not guaranteed to be high, what are you?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also find this 'undetermined' area in official doc. But my question is still there: why this area is undetermined? Related to what charactistics of hardware/circuit？Why could not design it as always determined?

Comment: There are three reasons:  (1) it is physically impossible to manufacture many millions of pieces of silicon over many years and have them all behave identically.  Different impurities in the raw material or differences in the process will result in very slightly different sensitivities.  The datasheet describes what they predict will be true for all parts.

Comment: (2) The sensitivity depends on temperature.  The datasheet describes what will be true at all allowed temperatures.  (3) They deliberately include some hysteresis so that if the input voltage is very close to the threshold it will not cause the input value to change rapidly back and forth which would waste a lot of power.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your valuable information. As to sensitivity, I thought the trigger value could be relatively close to the guaranteed value. For my case, I think the trigger value should be close to 2V instead of 1v. Will there be so big difference with the guaranteed value? My concern is there is some defect in our designed circuit that we do not notice yet.